# Retrieving data from a repeater ASP.net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater

I'm trying to retrieve some data from a repeater, the end goal is to send a bunch of data in to a table.

I'm using the following to access the repeater, however "FindControl" is underlined:

```
String prodName = ((Literal)Repeater1.ItemTemplate.FindControl("LitProdName")).Text;
```

However I get the warning:

*"Error   1   'System.Web.UI.ITemplate' does not contain a definition for 'FindControl' and no extension method 'FindControl' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Web.UI.ITemplate' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)   C:\Users\User\Desktop\WLL\WLL\ProductDetails.aspx.cs    62  68  WLL"*

The complete method is as follows:

```
public void AddToBasket()
    {

        {
            //String prodName = "Test";
            String prodName = ((Literal)Repeater1.ItemTemplate.FindControl("LitProdName")).Text;
            String prodID = Request.QueryString["productID"];
            String userName = User.Identity.Name;
            String size = "17.5";
            int price = 10;

            {
                var basket = new Basket();

                basket.User = userName;
                basket.ProductID = Convert.ToInt32(prodID);
                //basket.ProductName = prodName;
                basket.Size = size;
                basket.Price = price;

                using (ProductContext _db = new ProductContext())
                {

                    // By default, uses deferred execution for performance (doesn't get the data until it uses it)
                    // Calling ToList gets the data immediate
                    _db.Baskets.Add(basket);
                    _db.SaveChanges();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: show your .aspx /markup

Comment: <asp:Repeater ID="Repeater1" Visible="false" 
        runat="server" ItemType="WLL.Models.Product" 
        SelectMethod ="GetProduct">
        <ItemTemplate>

            
            <asp:Literal ID="LitProdName" runat="server" Text="<%#:Item.ProductName %>"></asp:Literal>
            
        </ItemTemplate>
        

    </asp:Repeater>

Answer (score 0):

You should do something like

```
foreach(RepeaterItem item in Repeater.Items) 
{
   var lit = item.FindControl("id");
    //code
}
```

Since the controls are in the items of the Repeater not in the ItemTemplate.

Comment: I gave that a go, but I still get the same error on FindControl